# XML column Data into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement where I have XML data column in database, which I need to pull in the form of values from rows XML data column from database. My XML is like

```
 <ListID><ID>169346</ID><ID>289492</ID><ID>315264</ID><ID>415265</ID></ListID>
 <ListID><ID>169356</ID><ID>299492</ID><ID>315264</ID><ID>415265</ID></ListID>
```

And I want data to be pulled up like

```
       ID
      169346
      289492
      315264
      415265
      169356
      299492
      315264
      415265
```

Comment: Your XML in the DB starting from <ListID> till </ListID> is in one column is it ?

Comment: "This one row in that column"

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT XC.value('.', 'int')
FROM dbo.YourTableHere
CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('//ID') AS XT(XC)
```

This basically takes every `<ID>` element that exists in the XML column, and extract the values as `int` and shows them in a result set.

**Update:** from your question, mentioning *I have XML data column*, I assumed that your column in the SQL Server table **is** in fact of type `XML`. And it should be, if you're storing XML in it!

But if it's not - then you need to cast your column to XML first, before using the function `.nodes()` in my code sample:

```
SELECT XC.value('.', 'int')
FROM dbo.YourTableHere
CROSS APPLY CAST(YourColumn AS XML).nodes('//ID') AS XT(XC)
```

Comment: I am getting error like "The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml"

Comment: @Malyadri: well, your column has to be of type `XML` - obviously. If it stores XML - then it **really** should be `XML` anyway ....

Comment: What marc_s said is totally true: you should store the contents of your XML column as an XML type. If you can't for some reason, cast the NVARCHAR column to XML first before applying the nodes function to it (`CAST(XmlColumn AS XML).nodes(...`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one other way is to convert it to `XML` & then convert it to row :

```
SELECT split.a.value('.', 'varchar(max)') ID
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST(ID AS XML) AS String from <table_name>
) a
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('//ID') AS split(a);
```

Result :

```
ID
169346
289492
315264
415265
169356
299492
315264
415265
```